# SoundConverter fails to convert mp4 to mp3

Tags: 18.04, gstreamer, soundconverter

Just installed SoundCOnverter 3 to my Ubuntu 18.04 box and I'm getting this error message after the sound convertion finishes...
`gst-stream-error-quark: internal data stream error. (1)`

I have to say that there's no MP3 file after this...

[image: SoundConverter GStreamer error]

Comment: Facing the same issue. It may be a soundconverter or gstreamer bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem. Found there was a workaround by converting to wav or flac first. However, to avoid this, I installed soundKonverter instead via package manager.